# How to retrieve the current page from Zend_Navigation within a Controller Plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-acl

I am working on an Authentication Plugin using a Controller Plugin. I define my navigation config within the application.ini file, and then use that and the Database user records to dynamically load the ACL and apply it to Zend_Navigation. This bit works, as it successfully loads the menu and only displays the pages the user is allowed to see.

However, this doesn't stop the user from going to the page directly. What I want to do is identify when the user is going to a page they don't have access to within the Controller Plugin so I can redirect their request to the Authentication page.

I was thinking there must be a function to retrieve the current page from Zend_Navigation, but I can't find it... so maybe it doesn't exist.

Anyway, this is my full Controller Plugin. Anyone see a solution?

```
<?php
class Pog_Model_AuthPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $oRequest)
    {
        /**
         * Load user
         */
        $oAuth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $oDbUsers = new Pog_Model_DbTable_Users();

        if (!$oAuth->hasIdentity())
        {
            $oUser       = $oDbUsers->createRow();
            $oUser->name = "guest";
            $oUser->setReadOnly(true);
        }
        else
        {
            $oUser = $oAuth->getIdentity();
            $oUser->setTable($oDbUsers);
        }

        /**
         * Load ACL
         */    
        $oAcl = new Zend_Acl();
        $oAcl->addRole($oUser->name);


        /**
         * Add current user privileges
         */
        $oPrivileges = $oUser->getPrivileges();
        foreach ($oPrivileges as $oPrivilege)
        {
            if (!$oAcl->has($oPrivilege->resource))
                $oAcl->addResource($oPrivilege->resource);

            $oAcl->allow($oUser->name, $oPrivilege->resource, $oPrivilege->privilege);
        }


        /**
         * Load Navigation view helper
         */
        $oViewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
        $oNavigation   = $oViewRenderer->view->navigation();


        /**
         * Add remaining Navigation resources
         */
        foreach ($oNavigation->getPages() as $oPage)
        {
            if (!is_null($oPage->getResource()) && !$oAcl->has($oPage->getResource()))
                $oAcl->addResource($oPage->getResource());
        }


        /**
         * Set ACL and Role
         */
        $oNavigation->setAcl($oAcl)->setRole($oUser->name);


        /**
         * Check if use is allowed to be here
         */
        ...MAGIC GOES HERE...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should be able to get current navigation page as follows:

```
     /**
     * Load Navigation view helper
     */
    $oViewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
    $oNavigation   = $oViewRenderer->view->navigation();

    /*@var $active array */        
    $active = $oNavigation->findActive($oNavigation->getContainer());

    /*@var $activePage Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc */   
    $activePage =  $active['page'];

    // example of getting page info        
    var_dump($activePage->getLabel(), $activePage->getController(), $activePage->getAction());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks like what I am after, but I am getting an empty array as a response. Could it have something to do with me running it in a Controller Plugin?

Comment: I just put some test code in a view script and the above works fine. It looks like the Navigation helper isn't fully setup when I get to it in the Controller Plugin, but it's fine after that... Now to find out when it gets setup and see if I can trigger it.

Comment: @Valorin. I tested the code in preDispatch of my acl controller plugin and it is ok. How do you setup your navigation? I setup navigation in in bootstrap.php? Maybe this is way in my case it is initialized?

Comment: @Marcin, I setup my Navigation in the application.ini file using the navigation resource, so it could be that. Although, that is a bit weird if it is. The code for Nav appears to pull the active Controller and Action via the Front Controller - so I assumed this wasn't set up yet.

Comment: @Valorin. This is how I initialize my nav in bootstrap.php: http://pastebin.com/TrCf0Bm5. Maybe this will be helpful.

Comment: I had the same problem in my layout, then I realized that I had the page set to 'visible = false', which was stopping it from being found by findActive()... So I'd say that was my problem from the start too. That's kinda annoying... I'll see if I can find a work around. Oh, and I'll accept your answer too :)

Comment: @Valorin. Thanks for the accept and hope you will overcome your problem.

Answer (score 0):

*This is the solution I used, since I can't get Marcin's solution working in my setup for some reason.*

I did some more thinking and thought of a nice simple solution to the problem. Rather than use the Navigation module to find the Active page, I find it myself. Since I am already iterating through the pages, it's a piece of cake to compare the Controller and Action - if these both match I have my Active page!

The new getPages() foreach loop looks like this:

```
$oCurrentPage = null;
foreach ($oNavigation->getPages() as $oPage)
{
    /**
     * Check for Current Page
     */
    if ($oPage->getController() == $oRequest->getControllerName()
      && $oPage->getAction() == $oRequest->getActionName())
        $oCurrentPage = $oPage;


    /**
     * Add Resource, if missing
     */
    if (!is_null($oPage->getResource()) && !$oAcl->has($oPage->getResource()))
        $oAcl->addResource($oPage->getResource());
}
```